# Installing and Configuring Windows 2008 SMTP Server

Tags: windows-server-2008, smtp

Trying to work out the process of enabling SMTP server on a Windows 2008 Server. I've enabled the SMTP feature within the Server Manager but I don't see where to configure it.

I need to be able to configure it to use a SmartHost.

Walk throughs appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the IIS6.0 compatible console in Windows/system32/inetsrv/iis.mmc (assuming it's been installed)

Cheers,
jmi

Comment: didn't realize there was a separate console for that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Jamie said, my understanding is you basically have to use the IIS 6 tools at this time. You can install them as a feature as outlined in [this article](http://www.crunchloop.com/2009/04/enabling-smtp-with-iis7.html) and from that point on it is fairly straight forward just like it is in 2003.